# Execution failed: react-native-fbsdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbsdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I tried all the solution that was posted on StackOverflow with the same topic.

```
:react-native-fbsdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
C:\Users\karol\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\bootkik-mobile\node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\src\main\java\com\facebook\reactnative\androidsdk\FBGraphRequestModule.java:155: error: no suitable constructor found for AccessToken(String,String,String,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>)
            graphRequest.setAccessToken(new AccessToken(
                                        ^
    constructor AccessToken.AccessToken(String,String,String,Collection<String>,Collection<String>,AccessTokenSource,Date,Date,Date) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor AccessToken.AccessToken(Parcel) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
C:\Users\karol\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\bootkik-mobile\node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\src\main\java\com\facebook\reactnative\androidsdk\Utility.java:64: error: no suitable constructor found for AccessToken(String,String,String,List<String>,List<String>,AccessTokenSource,Date,Date)
        return new AccessToken(
               ^
    constructor AccessToken.AccessToken(String,String,String,Collection<String>,Collection<String>,AccessTokenSource,Date,Date,Date) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor AccessToken.AccessToken(Parcel) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\karol\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\bootkik-mobile\node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\src\main\java\com\facebook\reactnative\androidsdk\Utility.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
:react-native-fbsdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbsdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.084 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Would like to know if anyone have a fix for this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Facebook broke their API with version 4.38 or 4.39 of module facebook-android-sdk. You have to depend on 4.37 to make your code compile.